# making xampp more secure

Tags: windows, security, windows-vista, xampp

does anyone know of a detailed security checklist somewhere to make xampp more secure for windows vista. I know about changing passwords and the basics, but I want to make sure my system is not vulnerable and I have a short time frame on a project. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm thinking about installing all the components separately if their defaults are set more securely that way??(not sure), unless someone has a better suggestion, hopefully, thanks!...

Answer (score 0):

I just read through this guide and it covers all of the security necessities for xampp:

http://bravo.newnetenterprises.com/wordpress/xampp/the-basics-of-xampp-security/

Also, you may want to consider putting a firewall in front of the server, [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/) is a nice open source solution for that

Comment: thanks! I will check it out. For now I just downloaded apache and php.